# Row based replication on slave where as statement based on Master

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication, kafka

We have a master slave setup of MYSQL 5.6. Master and slave runs SBR replication where as slave is not writing binlogs.

We need to enable binlogs on the Slave server but we want the binlogs to be in RBR format on the slave instead. We want to ship them to Kafka and it wants RBR replication only.

Is this doable to have RBR on the slave where as it is getting data from master as SBR ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any trouble. For you replication you use the binlogs in the master, and the your slave reads them and "translates" them to his relay logs. Then your slave executes that relay log and for the replication, that's it.

In fact, you have already "different" settings, since you weren't doing any binlogs at all in your slave, so enabling RBR won't do any harm.